# How to use async/await function response in another asyc/await function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have **two async/await** function, **first one is taking images and get response of images text, Second one needs to take response of first function as a parameter.**

**First async function**

```
const detecText = async (filename) => {
  let [result] = await client.textDetection(filename);
  const labels = result.textAnnotations[0].description;
  return labels;
};
```

as I am using this `detecText()` function with **multiple parameter from array** `ImagesName[]`

```
    ImagesNames.forEach((element) => {
    detecText(element)
      .then((result) => {
     console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        console.log(
          "loop not working!" +
            err +
            element
        )
      );
  
  });
```

Now I have second async/await function which has to **take parameter from above detecText() function**

```
const target = "en";

const translateText = async function translateText(text) {
  let [translations] = await translate.translate(text, target);
  translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];

  translations.forEach((translation, i) => { 
    return translation;
  });
};
```

How can I use this `translateText()` function with **parameter from the response** of `deteText()` function ?

Comment: `foreach` isn't meant for handling async tasks in a loop. You might want to use a normal `for` loop or something like `promise.all`.

Comment: could you please elaborate ?

Comment: That final `forEach` loop is doing nothing useful. What did you intend to do there?

Comment: hey can go through this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: First detecText is taking parameter from an array and return response, then the response of detecText use as a parameter in translateText() to get response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can call your function `translateText` in the callback for `then` after the call of `detecText`.

You can do both ways:

```
detecText(element).then((result) => {
  return translateText(result);
})

// or simplified

detecText(element).then(translateText);
```

Second problem, is to wait for all the promises and getting all results in one place. For that you might need `Promise.all`.

```
  let translations;

  try {
    const translationPromises = ImagesNames.map((element) => {
      return detecText(element).then(translateText);
    };
    translations = await Promise.all(translationPromises);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('o_O error', err);
  }
```

Overall, I'd advice you to get more practice with `Promise` API first, not with `async/await` sugar.

Comment: How can I write each response in separate .txt file from `detecText(element).then((result) => {
  return translateText(result);
})
`